# How can I set PATH in the `dash`(or bash) shell so that it doesn't search any dirs ? because empty PATH searches current directory

Tags: bash, path, dash

In [Dash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash) if I set the `PATH` to an empty string, it searches in current directory:

```
$ export PATH=
$ echo $PATH

$ emptyexe
$ /usr/bin/ls emptyexe
emptyexe
$ pwd
/home/ctor
$ cd ..
$ emptyexe
dash: 36: emptyexe: not found
```

What do I set `PATH` to so that it's guaranteed to not search in any directory, least of all the current one ?

An empty `PATH` also searches the current directory in Bash, so the question applies to it, too.

This is on Fedora 28 (an AppVM in Qubes OS actually):

```
$ rpm -qf `which dash`
dash-0.5.9-1.fc25.x86_64
$ rpm -qf `which bash`
bash-4.3.43-4.fc25.x86_64
```

Comment: I removed the part of your post that was actually a separate question (as you said yourself, it's a separate issue). It only worked to confuse readers from the question you set in the title. You can post the other question as, well, another question.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you, it is much cleaner now! Cheers!

Comment: Just for reference, the bash manual does describe this behavior in Section 5.1 Bourne Shell Variables: "A colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands. A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example `$ export PATH=/dev/null` should do it.

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ dash
$ echo 'echo meh' > nonemptyexe
$ /usr/bin/chmod a+x ./nonemptyexe
$ nonemptyexe
dash: 3: nonemptyexe: not found
$ ./nonemptyexe
meh
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ctor/.local/bin:/home/ctor/bin
$ export PATH=/dev/null
$ nonemptyexe
dash: 7: nonemptyexe: not found
$ ./nonemptyexe
meh
$ echo $PATH
/dev/null
$ export PATH=""
$ echo $PATH

$ nonemptyexe
meh
$ ./nonemptyexe
meh
$
```